# Google App Engine Data store issue: Getting TypeError: Cannot set non-property when trying to insert into DataSTore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Model definition

```
class SeqNumbers(ndb.Model):
"""APNS Server -- SeqNumbers object that stores sequence number of stored messages between two devices"""
  SeqNumberStart = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
  SeqNumberEnd = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
  Sourcein = ndb.StringProperty
  Destin = ndb.StringProperty
```

Code to add to Datastore.  This results in the 
TypeError: Cannot set non-property Sourcein (full error at end of the post)

Any help in understanding what is happening will be greatly appreciated.

```
data ={}
data['SeqNumberStart']=0
data['SeqNumberEnd']=0
data['key']=seqKey
data['Sourcein']='user_IOT'
data['Destin']='user_SmartHome'
SeqNumbers(**data).put()
```

Full Error in GAE logs

```
E 02:08:17.725 Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: TypeError (Cannot set non-property Sourcein)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
      response = method(instance, request)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1332, in invoke_remote
      return remote_method(service_instance, request)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 414, in invoke_remote_method
      response = method(service_instance, request)
    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388953439373110592/apns_server.py", line 588, in sendMsg
      SeqNumbers(**data).put()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2942, in __init__
      self._set_attributes(kwds)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2987, in _set_attributes
      raise TypeError('Cannot set non-property %s' % name)
  TypeError: Cannot set non-property Sourcein
```

Comment: Would dropping the `key` from the `data` dict make any difference? You don't have a `key` property in the model (and I *think* I saw a note mentioning that naming a property `key` is not allowed, but I can no longer find it...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize the properties for Sourcein and Destin. Just put the parenthesis at the end:

```
Sourcein = ndb.StringProperty()
Destin = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Comment: Adding parentheses was the key for us

Comment: I had a similar issue. I used `ndb.StringProperty()` instead of `db.StringProperty()` to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the old `google.appengine.ext.db` which used the [`name` keyword argument to give an alias](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/ad688b7ca2de2bf3e1be5d53963fb80639fb8d24/src/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#L565C1-L566C43):

```
class ModelClass:
    amt = db.FloatProperty(required=True, name="amount")
```

> name: Storage name for property.
>
> By default, uses attribute name as it is assigned in the `Model` sub-class.

Then I upgraded to `ndb`. `ndb` [**does** support the `name` keyword argument](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/ad688b7ca2de2bf3e1be5d53963fb80639fb8d24/src/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#L919) (at first I thought the `name` keyword argument was the problem here)...

I also had a [Python property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (not an `ndb` Property) defined like this:

```
class ModelClass:
     ....
     @property
     def amount(self):
         return #...
```

I got the error "Cannot set non-property..." with [`ndb` because it uses `getattr(cls, prop_name)`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/ad688b7ca2de2bf3e1be5d53963fb80639fb8d24/src/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#L3080) and finds my Python property (**not** an `ndb.Property`)

However [`db` checks `self.properties()`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/ad688b7ca2de2bf3e1be5d53963fb80639fb8d24/src/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#L973), which does **not** find my Python property.